# Share data between two view controllers via userDeafults

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiswitch

I'm creating UISwitch that controls two view controllers, and I need to share data of UISwitch condition between them. I tried to use User Defaults but got SIGABRT error. What do I need to fix to get it working?

```
// Its view with UISwitch

@IBAction func SwitchThemeColor(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    if SwitchTheme.isOn || traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "switchState")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }


// And that is the view where I want to transfer UISwitch condition

if  UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "switchState") == true {
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        }
```

expected: that data transfers and switch controls background of two views

actual: SIGABRT error and it did not work

also I write bt in output and get this:

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x00007fff513782c6 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
    frame #1: 0x00007fff5141fbf1 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 284
    frame #2: 0x00007fff51308a5c libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 120
    frame #3: 0x00007fff4f22e7f8 libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 231
    frame #4: 0x00007fff4f22e9c7 libc++abi.dylib`demangling_terminate_handler() + 262
    frame #5: 0x00007fff503b5d7c libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 96
    frame #6: 0x00007fff4f23be97 libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
    frame #7: 0x00007fff4f23be39 libc++abi.dylib`std::terminate() + 41
    frame #8: 0x00007fff503b5d1c libobjc.A.dylib`objc_terminate + 9
    frame #9: 0x000000010ff1cd78 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 28
    frame #10: 0x000000010ff1fcd5 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 300
    frame #11: 0x00007fff3633108a FrontBoardServices`__FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 30
    frame #12: 0x00007fff36330d78 FrontBoardServices`-[FBSSerialQueue _queue_performNextIfPossible] + 441
    frame #13: 0x00007fff36331287 FrontBoardServices`-[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 22
    frame #14: 0x00007fff23afbac1 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    frame #15: 0x00007fff23afb9ec CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 76
    frame #16: 0x00007fff23afb21c CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 268
    frame #17: 0x00007fff23af5ecf CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1263
    frame #18: 0x00007fff23af56b6 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 438
    frame #19: 0x00007fff3815cbb0 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 65
    frame #20: 0x00007fff47162a67 UIKitCore`UIApplicationMain + 1621
  * frame #21: 0x000000010fa7bdab TabbedAppTest`main at AppDelegate.swift:12:7
    frame #22: 0x00007fff5123bcf5 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #23: 0x00007fff5123bcf5 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Comment: Have you tried putting in breakpoints to debug through? Does it reach the condition where it checks if your userdefault is true?

Comment: try `if  UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "switchState") as! Bool == true` . And be careful about force unwrapping.

Comment: @SoroushShahi tried it and get: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<TabbedAppTest.SecondViewController 0x7f8d84516c60> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key BarItem.'

Comment: You need to set an initial value for `switchState` in UserDefaults. Where is that being done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is somewhere else - this code should works.

You mention in comment, that you get error message: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<TabbedAppTest.SecondViewController 0x7f8d84516c60> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key BarItem.`

It looks like you have in storyboard/xib file some old outlet for key `BarItem` in you `SecondViewController` class. Probably you removed outlet from code programmatically, but outlet in storyboard/xib stays.

Comment: you were right, problem was somewhere else, I create new project and now everything works.